# Firebase storage rule check if custom claims list contains value (hasAll, hasAny, etc)

Tags: firebase-storage, firebase-security

**-- UPDATE --**

It turns out the below should have worked, but didn't due to a bug, so this was recommended by Firebase Support as a workaround, and it worked for me:

`request.auth.token.permissions.toSet().hasAll([0])`

**-----------------------------**

I have an array/list of with a single integer on my custom claims like this:

```
someList: [0]
```

I want to check if a number exists in the list in my storage security rules.  I can't seem to get the `hasAll` rule to work that is mentioned in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#hasall

Some rules work when referencing the list so I know for sure that the property is there in my custom claims, but I can't seem to get it to work with `hasAll` or using tricks with strings.

Example -

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /clients/{clientId}/{allPaths=**} {      
      // These work - 
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList.join('').size() > 0
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList != null

      // These do not -
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList.hasAll([0])
      allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList.join('').matches('0')
    }
  }
}
```

‍♂️  ?

Comment: The rules that work dont actually check for the integer. Are you sure your custom claims is properly set?

Comment: Can your try: `allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList is list`

Comment: And `allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList.size() == 1`

Comment: @l1b3rty I tried both `is list` and `size() == 1` and those work fine, but still not `hasAll([0])` ☹️

Comment: and I did `admin().auth().getUser()` in a firebase function and I for sure have `someList: [0]` in my customClaims.

Comment: Have you write any data to `someList` before you write `0` to it?

Comment: Could you try re login your app?

Comment: @flutroid I have tried re-setting the custom claims and also re-logging in and no luck.

Comment: Try `allow read, write: if 0 in request.auth.token.someList`

Comment: @chevin99 Ok, But beware that when you update custom claims it won't also update data in rules immdetely see this [Firebase custom claims are not update in rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280361/firebase-custom-claims-are-not-update-in-rules)

Comment: @l1b3rty `allow read, write: if 0 in request.auth.token.someList` didn't work either 

Comment: @flutroid I had made sure to force the token refresh client-side, but still no luck ☹️.

Comment: In your client, can you try calling `getidtoken` with `forceRefresh` set to true before making the call? And still in the client, log the token you get back https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken

Comment: @l1b3rty thanks, yes, I've done that and the values are there on the claims.  I should also point out I've been using that same `someList: [0]` for firestore rules for quite some time and they work, but haven't gotten it to work with storage rules yet.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you can do:

1. Confirm custom claims are properly set and refreshed: in your client, try calling [`getidtoken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.User#getidtoken) with `forceRefresh` set to true before making the call, log the data you get back.
2. Check if the following rules pass:

   ```
   allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList is list;
   allow read, write: if request.auth.token.someList.size() == 1;
   allow read, write: if 0 in request.auth.token.someList;
   ```

Comment: I'm probably going to open a ticket with firebase since I would assume one of those work but I had no luck with any.  Thanks.

Comment: It was indeed a bug.  See workaround in original question. 