# Check if a user confirmed his email on another device

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to check if a user confirmed his email on another device, i.e. opened the email.

My hacky way is to check with `setInterval` every 2secs and check `auth.currentUser.emailVerified` Is there any way to subscribe to auth updates? like confirming email, adding a phone, or changing his displayName?

Comment: Well, if you attempt to login a user, won't it tell you that it isn't verified?

Comment: The user is creating the account, I'm waiting for him to confirm his email in order to navigate him.

Comment: So, you want him to automatically be logged in as soon as he clicks on the verification link?

Comment: Yeah, on his phone, the form is waiting for him to confirm/click the link.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to subscribe to auth updates?

If the user is signed in on the device, it already receives the latest user profile every hour (when the ID token refreshes). Aside from these automatic updates there is no built-in refresh for out-of-band updates like email verification or updates that happen on another device.

There are a few common ways to deal with this scenario, polling being one of them (although every 2 seconds seems a bit excessive).

For more on this exact problem, see  [Angular firebase email verification false after verify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54592255/angular-firebase-email-verification-false-after-verify/54594760#54594760), and the links I included there.